# Angular import @angular/http dynamically from the code

Tags: angular, import, libraries

Is there any way to import @angular/http into a variable not using the famous:

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http'
```

I want to import the @angular/http or any other library programmatically.
any idea ?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? Why such requirement?

Comment: I already did an Angular Core application that is already published. Now this Core application loads modules dynamically from a certain path. 
when loading modules, one of these modules needs @angular/http so i want to import this library directly from the code

Comment: can't you use `require` for this?

Comment: Can you give me an example plz. i am new to angular

Answer (score 1):

If you want the dynamic access to the modules, you can use the `require`. `require` has one parameter `string` name of module.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

declare var require: any
// use http anywhere in your project
// if need to access all the functions from http module by using .
export const http = require('@angular/common/http');

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'demong';

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

You can also get modules dynamically at runtime by,

```
export class Demo {
   getModule(moduleName: string) {
       return require(moduleName);
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this still require you to know the name of the module at build time? Will this code work if the module name isn't know until runtime?

Comment: The last snippet will help you in that. Consider this as a factory design pattern, you provide the string of name of the module, and if the module is available you will get the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use import as a function:

> The import keyword may be called as a function to dynamically import a
>   module. When used this way, it returns a promise.

```
import('/modules/my-module.js')
  .then((module) => {
    // Do something with the module.
  });
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import